# How do I work with specific class instances in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to make a small application where users can create a list of stores and inventories for the stores. Here's what I have for the store class:

```
class Store
  attr_accessor :name, :inventory
  
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @inventory = []
    @@all << self
  end

end
```

It initializes with an empty array, and I want to fill it up with items (as strings). I'm aware you can use, say `newStore = Store.new` to create a store and then further call on `newStore`, but I want the user to be able to create as many stores as they want and when they create a second `newStore` it will override that variable. How do I re-access that previous class instance to edit the inventory array?

Comment: You mean you want a class-level `inventory`? That aside: are you *sure* you want that? I'd be more likely to model this in a different way; it sounds like you're missing an abstraction.

Comment: Well, I thought it would be tidier to have the inventory tied to each instance of Store, as long as I could refer to each individual instance of Store, I could get the inventory. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Without context it's difficult to say. But a "collection of stores" doesn't seem like something the `Store` class should be interested in. For example, it means putting "collection of stores" logic in `Store` (e.g., "what other store(s) has this inventory item?"), or a utility class that takes a store (or uses the `Store` class directly). If it's the former, I think it's in the wrong place. If it's the latter, then why keep the collection of stores in `Store` then if the logic that uses it lives somewhere else?

Comment: _"when they create a second newStore it will override that variable"_ – if the user wants two stores, they could assign them to _different_ variables, e.g. `store_1 = Store.new` and `store_2 = Store.new`. Or the user could create an array `stores = []` and push new stores to that array via `stores << Store.new` – as many as they want. The stores can then be accessed via `stores[0]`, `stores[1]`, etc. In any way, this is not something the `Store` class should handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it to the following and just create a new array when it wasn't initialized before:

```
def initialize(name)
  @name = name
  @inventory = []
  @@all ||= []
  @@all << self
end
```

Comment: Consider offering some advice about the use of class variables...

Comment: Maybe extract that into a class method and use a class instance variable instead, i.e. `def self.all ; @all ||= [] ; end`. This would also allow to retrieve stores from the array, e.g. `Store.all.find { |s| s.name == 'Walmart' }` .